# Switch views with button

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have two views. The User view has some text and a button. I want to use that button to switch to the second view. But i don't know how this works with sencha touch 2. When i press the button on the "UserView" (which is the first view), then i get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

This is basically how my code looks right now:

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.setup({
    viewport: {
        autoMaximize: false
    },
    onReady: function() {
        var app = new Ext.Application({
            name: 'AM',
            controllers: [
                'Main'
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

**The Main controller**

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views : ['User'],
    init: function() {
        this.getUserView().create();

        this.control ({
            '#new': {
               tap: function() {
                    alert('aaaa');
               }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**And the two views:**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        fullscreen:true,
        items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'New',
                id: 'new'
            }
        ],
        html: 'Testing<br />'
    }
});
```

**2nd view**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.New', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        html: 'w00t'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is your application written the way it should be. Here are a few notes about the changes I made:

- You should call `Ext.application` instead of `Ext.setup` when creating your MVC application.
- All root views should be defined inside your **app.js**.
- You no longer need to use `this.control()` in your controllers. You can simply use the control configuration in the config block.
- You should define all views in the `views` config of `Ext.application`.
- Instead of creating the view in `init`, do it in `launch`. This is components should be added into the view.

**app/view/User.js**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'New',
                id: 'new'
            }
        ],
        html: 'Testing<br />'
    }
});
```

**app/view/New.js**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.New', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        html: 'w00t'
    }
});
```

**app/controller/Main.js**

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {
            '#new': {
                // On the tap event, call onNewTap
                tap: 'onNewTap'
            }
        }
    },

    launch: function() {
        // When our controller is launched, create an instance of our User view and add it to the viewport
        // which has a card layout
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('AM.view.User'));
    },

    onNewTap: function() {
        // When the user taps on the button, create a new reference of our New view, and set it as the active
        // item of Ext.Viewport
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('AM.view.New'));
    }
});
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    // Include the only controller
    controllers: ['Main'],

    // Include all views
    views: ['User', 'New'],

    // Give the Ext.Viewport global instance a custom layout and animation
    viewport: {
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'left',
                duration: 300
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I also suggest you checkout the great guides over on the [Sencha Touch API Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app), as well as checking out the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums) as they are very active and are a great source of information.